Missing "Visual C++" option when creating project from existing code in Visual Studio
I want to create a C++ project from existing code in Visual Studio. Following Microsoft's instructions, I selected File > New > Project From Existing Code. The screenshot in the guide shows an option for Visual C++. However, the code project wizard only gave me options to create a Visual Basic or C# project. I am running Visual Studio Community 2022 (17.12.3) on Windows 11.
Why am I missing the option to create a C++ project from existing code in Visual Studio?


Resolved by installing the "Desktop development with C++" workload for Visual Studio.

Open Visual Studio Installer
Find your version of Visual Studio and click Modify
Select the Workloads tab
Check the option for Desktop development with C++
Select Modify and wait for installation to complete


